# Is it permitted to eat cooked (non-meat) food without a hechsher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

If someone has food given to them without a hechsher but one is unsure of the ingredients other than the fact that it doesn't contain meat, are there heterim to allow it's consumption seeing that perhaps all of the issurim are only (safek) d'rabbanan?

Comment: There are other reasons for food to be prohibited, not just that it contained non-kosher meat. For one example consider the possibility of insects being present in unchecked vegetables which would constitute an Torah prohibition.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok this is assuming the person that wants to eat the food does whatever they can to ensure it's kashrus from that point (e.g checking for insects, looking for meat, inquiring about the taste of meat, etc.)

Comment: I’m tempted to flag this as too broad. There are just too many Halachos to consider.

Comment: @DonielF It isnt too broad. The question of "is X permitted" is a single question.

Comment: I disagree with the title edit. Motion to roll back

Comment: @mevaqesh That’s not what the original version read, though. I agree with DoubleAA’s motion to rollback.

Comment: I might not have gotten it across properly, but this is definitely a bedieved situation (i.e the food is already prepared/present), not trying to ask on planning to eat parve out

Comment: @DoubleAA body asks are there heterim. that's a yes or no question: is it permitted, followed by an implicit second question: if it is permitted, why. Seems like the edit gets that across better...

Comment: @DonielF ^^^^^^

Comment: @mevaqesh Probably the better question to ask here is: what does the OP think about the edit? Does he agree with it or did he prefer the original version?

Comment: @Fei23 ^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch says in [סימן סח - דין תפלת הדרך ושאר דברים שצריכין לזהר בדרך](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0067_L2) that when staying by somebody one should carefully investigate the kashrut standards of one's host before eating.

> בַּאַכְסַנְיָא שֶׁהוּא אוֹכֵל שָׁמָּה, צָרִיךְ לְדַקְדֵּק אִם בַּעַל הַבַּיִת וְאַנְשֵׁי בֵיתוֹ הֵמָה כְּשֵׁרִים וְנֶאֱמָנִים. וְאִם רוֹצֶה לֶאֱכֹוֹל בָּשָׂר בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָדוּעַ לוֹ, צָרִיךְ לַחְקוֹר וְלִדְרוֹשׁ הֵיטֵב מִי הוּא הַשּׁוֹחֵט וּמִי הוּא הָרַב הַמַּשְׁגִּיחַ עָלָיו, כִּי בַּעֲוֹנוֹתֵנוּ הָרַבִּים רַבָּה הַמַּכְשֵׁלָה, וְהַמַּשְׂכִּיל יָבִין. וּמִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן בַּיַיִן, אֲשֶׁר בַּעֲוֹנוֹתֵנוּ הָרַבִּים רַבּוּ הַמִּתְפָּרְצִים, וּצְרִיכִין חֲקִירָה וּדְרִישָׁה (יו"ד סִימָן קי"ט). ‏

This seems to imply that one cannot simply assume that a *frum Jew* wouldn't serve one something problematic.

He says that because of the current level of Yiddishkeit, one has to be very careful.

Presumably, he's referring to the more lenient position as recorded in Shulchan Aruch.

In Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah [סימן סח - דין תפלת הדרך ושאר דברים שצריכין לזהר בדרך](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_17.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2) it seems to say that as long as the person providing the food isn't suspected of eating forbidden foods, one may eat his food without investigating.

The Rema seems to argue and say that if one doesn't know him personally one cannot buy from him foods that are problematic, but if one is his guest one may eat with him.

> **א** הֶחָשׁוּד לֶאֱכֹל דְּבָרִים הָאֲסוּרִים, בֵּין אִם הוּא חָשׁוּד בְּאִסוּר תּוֹרָה בֵּין אִם הוּא חָשׁוּד בְּאִסוּר דְּרַבָּנָן, אֵין לִסְמֹךְ עָלָיו בָּהֶם; וְאִם נִתְאָרַח עִמּוֹ, לֹא יֹאכַל מִשֶּׁלוֹ מִדְּבָרִים שֶׁהוּא חָשׁוּד עֲלֵיהֶם. **הגה**: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים אֲפִלּוּ מִמִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ חָשׁוּד, רַק שֶׁאֵין מַכִּירִין אוֹתוֹ שֶׁהוּא מֻחְזָק בְּכַשְׁרוּת, אָסוּר לִקְנוֹת מִמֶּנּוּ יַיִן אוֹ שְׁאָר דְּבָרִים שֶׁיֵּשׁ לָחוּשׁ  לְאִסּוּר. מִיהוּ אִם נִתְאָרַח אֶצְלוֹ, אוֹכֵל עִמּוֹ (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הַרַמְבַּ''ם פי''א דמ''א ופ''ג דִּין כ''א) .‏
>
> **ב** אִם אֵינוֹ  חָשׁוּד לֶאֱכֹל דְּבָרִים אֲסוּרִים, אֲבָל הוּא חָשׁוּד לְמָכְרָם, מִתְאָרֵחַ אֶצְלוֹ וְאוֹכֵל עִמּוֹ. וְכֵן אִם שׁוֹלֵחַ לְבֵיתוֹ, מֻתָּר, דַּחֲזָקָה שֶׁמַּה שֶּׁהוּא אוֹכֵל מְשַׁגֵּר לוֹ. עוֹבֵר עֲבֵרָה לְתֵאָבוֹן, לֹא מִקְרֵי חָשׁוּד (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הָרַשְׁבָּ''א) .‏

So it would depend on who gave you the food without a hechsher - is it somebody you can rely on? Is it somebody you know? Is it a stranger who looks reliable? Is it a friendly shopkeeper who is obviously Jewish but doesn't seem religious?

(And it may also depend on how you look. Is there a possibility this *clearly pious person* mistook you for a non-Jew?)

If, as your question seems to indicate, the item seems to be suspicious - Kashrut-wise - it would appear that you need to thoroughly investigate the Kashrut before eating the product.

Comment: Would safek drabanan be relevant to non meat bdiavad? That seems to me to be main question.

Comment: @mevaqesh - as you can see from the quotes, you're not really given any leeway - if you don't know the guy (or you know too much about him) you have to treat any/all food as suspicious. Meat is worse according to the Kitzur, as you can't even trust the host, you have to check from the butcher all the way back to the Schochet.